# jQuery UI: Dynamically add elements to sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a sortable list dynamically, however when adding elements dynamically the sortable starts to behave incorrectly:

```
function buildHTML() {
    var selection = ['number', 'items', 'list'];
    var component = $('#selector');
    component.empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        component.append('<li class="drag-button"> ' + selection[i] + '</li>');
    }

    component.sortable('refresh');
}

$('#selector').sortable({ 
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    cursor: 'move',
    axis: 'x'
});

buildHTML();
```

Often while dragging slowly the item that's being dragged will be able to cross another item without moving to the empty position.

An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LRkg4/

While dragging the item "number" it is often able to get past the item "list" without "list" moving to the left. It feels completely different, not as snappy, from the static version: http://jsfiddle.net/cbXK3/1/ where I first build the HTML and then create the sortable:

```
buildHTML();
$('#selector').sortable({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is strange.  Viewing the source between the two looks identical.  Must be something under the jQuery hood that's not right.

This probably isn't the answer you were looking for but it works, the item sorting is snappy.  A simple destroy, add your dynamic items, then rebuild: **http://jsfiddle.net/BzfY3/3/**  (see fiddle for everything)

```
<ul id="selector">
    <li class="drag-button">some</li>
    <li class="drag-button">inital</li>
    <li class="drag-button">stuff</li>
</ul>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Add some sortable items and rebuild it" onclick="reBuildIt()">

<script>
//this function will destroy, add your new items, then rebuild it
window.reBuildIt=function() {
    var selection = ['number', 'items', 'list'];
    var component = $('#selector');
    component.sortable('destroy');

    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        component.append('<li class="drag-button"> ' +
        selection[i] + 
        '</li>');
    }

    $('#selector').sortable({ tolerance: 'pointer', cursor: 'move', axis: 'x' }); 
}

//show any initial sortable items
$('#selector').sortable({ tolerance: 'pointer', cursor: 'move', axis: 'x' });
</script>
```

Comment: I found that it is related to the empty <ul>. When I add a <li> in the HTML it seems to work as it should. So probably sortable caches some variables when initialising and doesn't update those on refresh! http://jsfiddle.net/p88Hf/1/